# Azure Devops Release Pipeline - git cloning fails due to long file name

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to build a simple release pipeline in Azure Devops that uses an Azure git repo as an artifact and Windows VM (ADO hosted agent). In our Azure repo, some file names are long around 240-244 characters but when they are downloaded into the ADO's agent directories they are reaching the 260 character limit. When I try to deploy using this release pipeline, ADO attempts to clone the git repo but fails each time with the error "Filename too long" shown below. I understand that the filename limit in git on a Windows machine is 260 characters and that the problem can normally be fixed by running `git config --global core.longpaths true` but the ADO release pipeline does not allow running a custom script before it automatically performs a checkout/clone, so I am not able to run git config either.

Errors in the log:

```
error: unable to create file unpacked-files/return-to-the-testplace/basic-form/_abc---test-appointment-regis-thedependent-for-existing-(student-codesrequired)/_abc---Test-Appointment-Register-Dependent-for-existing-(Student-Code-Required).javascript.custom_javascript.js: Filename too long

An error occurred during download: System.InvalidOperationException: Git checkout failed with exit code: 1
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Build.GitSourceProvider.GetSourceAsync(IExecutionContext executionContext, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.Artifacts.TfsGitArtifact.DownloadAsync(IExecutionContext executionContext, ArtifactDefinition artifactDefinition, String downloadFolderPath)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.ReleaseJobExtension.<>c__DisplayClass39_2.<<DownloadArtifacts>b__2>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.RetryExecutor.ExecuteAsync(Func`1 action)
```

Looking for ideas.

Comment: If you switch to [yaml pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-multi-stage-pipeline/), you can control when [checkout step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#checkout) is performed and run `git config` script beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update that on a Windows VM in an ADO pipeline, I am not sure if there exists a way to update the limit that the file system sets on the length of absolute paths of a file (including file name). In other words, the length of a file's directory + name (absolute path) cannot be greater than 260. In our pipeline, we had to update the directory/file name in such a way that it brought the length of the absolute path to be within the limit, and that fixed the issue with git clone.

Comment: Since you were able to solve it yourself, consider marking your answer as accepted: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Devops Release Pipeline - git cloning fails due to long file name

If you are using the Classic mode release pipeline, you could uncheck Select all artifacts in Artifact download section of agent phase:

[image]

If you are using YAML pipeline, you could `- download: none` to skip download the artifact.

You could check the document [Download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#download) for some more details:

```
steps:
- download: [ current | pipeline resource identifier | none ] # disable automatic download if "none"
  artifact: string ## artifact name, optional; downloads all the available artifacts if not specified
  patterns: string # patterns representing files to include; optional
  displayName: string  # friendly name to display in the UI
```

Comment: Thanks Leo. I have tried that approach but keep running into the error below. <br/> 

2021-09-10T16:39:52.7244454Z ##[debug]STDERR: Cloning into '<repo name>'...
2021-09-10T16:39:55.3783206Z ##[error]Cloning into '<repo name>'... <br/> 

I am using a Powershell script to clone my repo like shown below. I am pretty sure that my PAT is working correctly. <br/> 

$MyPat = '<token>'
$B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":$MyPat"))
git -c http.extraHeader="Authorization: Basic $B64Pat" -c core.longpaths=true clone <repo url>

Comment: Please ignore the comment above. The way I am using git clone with redundant arguments is incorrect. I also tried using: git config --global --add http.extraHeader "AUTHORIZATION: Basic $B64Pat"
git -c core.longpaths=true clone "<git repo url>" but the same error.... 2021-09-13T15:32:07.8963706Z ##[debug]STDERR: Cloning into '<repo>'...
2021-09-13T15:32:09.8599974Z ##[error]Cloning into '<repo>'...
2021-09-13T15:32:09.8611210Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error]Cloning into '<repo>'...

Comment: I would appreciate a sample powershell or bash script, if someone has one, that can clone an azure repo using PAT in the release pipeline.

Comment: @AdhishGupta, This should be another question about how to use git command line clone the file with long name. For this thread, we are concerned about your question is "ADO release pipeline does not allow running a custom script before it automatically performs a checkout/clone", If you want to resolve the question with your git command, you need open a new thread with your git command and the result.

Comment: The direction that you suggested made sense but it still did not solve my problem. Just FYI. Even with using git clone in a powershell script as shown in the code samples above, I still keep running into cloning issues. Have spent a few days on it already. The only resolution to my problem so far is to shorten the file names such that the length of the file name + length of the ADO working directory path is less than 260 characters.